# Any way to delete a merge request in a project that has been deleted in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I've recently started experimenting with GitLab, and I had created a test project to experiment with the different functions it offers. I created a merge request within the project, decided I was done with the experiment project, and then deleted the project. Now, I am stuck with a merge request that is under my name both for ownership and review in my notifications, but it does not exist within the list where merge requests should be, nor do I have access to the project to delete it there.
Is there any way to clear the "ghost" merge requests without clearing my account?

Comment: Deleting the project should remove the merge requests entirely. If you're using gitlab.com, it might resolve itself after some time (give it a day), or you may just have to open a support ticket otherwise.

Comment: It looks like waiting did solve the issue after two days